# how to create multiple action for one button within another event?

Tags: java, swing, events

I would like to run through a menu with sub-menus but when i use this cascade style for the sub-menu the action on "enter" only does the first on in the sequence and does not do the rest. any help is appreciated.

```
 open.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
         String text;
      double amt;
      String bal;
     double ir;
    String name;
       String acbal;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
            screen.setText("Press s for savings or c for checking");

            save.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    screen.setText("Enter name");
                    //get name
                     enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){



                            //balance
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                            text= entering.getText();   
                            name=text;
                                entering.setText(null);
                                screen.setText("enter account balance");
                                //bal
                                enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                     bal=entering.getText();
                                         amt = Double.parseDouble(bal); 
                                         entering.setText(null);


                                         //interest
                                         screen.setText("enter interest rate");
                                         enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


                                            public void actionPerformed(
                                                    ActionEvent e) {
                                                bal=entering.getText();
                                                ir=Double.parseDouble(bal);
                                                entering.setText(null);
                                                screen.setText("enter account number");

                                                enter.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){


                                                    public void actionPerformed(
                                                            ActionEvent e) {
                                                        text=entering.getText();
                                                        acbal=text;
                                                        entering.setText(null);
                                                        screen.setText("Commands : O- Open Account\n"+
                                                                   "           D- Deposit\n"+
                                                                   "           W- Withdraw\n"+
                                                                   "           I- Pay Interest\n"+
                                                                   "           T- Transaction");
                                                    }

                                                });
                                            }


                                         });
                                    }

                                });

                            }

                        });
                     //


                    SavingAccount sav = new SavingAccount(name,acbal,amt,ir);
                    banker.add(sav);
                }

            });//open account action

        } 

    });
```

Comment: Please tell us more of the details of your code and your problem so that we might understand your problem better. Strongly consider refactoring that code so that it is easier to read, understand, modify, and debug.

Comment: Edit: no, on second thought, after reading your code, don't refactor it. Sorry to be blunt, but you should scrap it completely and instead define just what you're trying to do, because that code is not what you want. The little bit of explanation that you've got posted is not written clearly and hard, at least for me, to parse and understand. If you put a little effort int re-writing this, I think that we'll have a much greater chance of being able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing here because when this was written, your question was very incomplete, but having said that, it looks like you want a collection of components that will get input from the user, but you want the specific input obtained to change, depending on the "state" of the program. So, for example, when this code starts, you want this collection of components to get a name, and then after that is complete, you want it to get an account balance, and so on.

If that is the case, then consider writing code for a class that creates a JPanel explicitly for this purpose, and that responds to changes in the *state* of the program by changing prompts and doing different things with the input entered.

For example, let's simplify your problem to one where we want the user to enter information for name, address, and city. So let's create an enum to encapsulate these states:

```
enum InputState {
   NAME("Name"), ADDRESS("Address"), CITY("City"), DONE("Done");

   private String text;

   private InputState(String text) {
      this.text = text;
   }
   public String getText() {
      return text;
   }
}
```

Then we can create a JPanel that holds the components of interest, and that can be allowed to change prompts and JButton Actions as desired:

```
class GetInputPanel extends JPanel {
   // almost arbitrary numbers below. 
   // you'll want to change this
   private static final int PREF_W = 500; 
   private static final int PREF_H = 40;
   private JLabel promptLabel = new JLabel();
   private JTextField inputField = new JTextField(10);
   private JButton doActionButton = new JButton();

   public GetInputPanel() {
      add(promptLabel);
      add(inputField);
      add(doActionButton);
   }

   // the most important method
   // allow outside objects the ability to change
   // our JButton and JTextField's Action
   public void setAction(Action action) {
      inputField.setAction(action);
      doActionButton.setAction(action);
      // note that setting a JButton's Action
      // will change its text and the action it 
      // performs on being pressed
   }

   // allow outside objects the ability to change
   // our promptLabel's text
   public void setPrompt(String prompt) {
      promptLabel.setText(prompt);
   }

   public String getInputText() {
      return inputField.getText();
   }

   public void clearInputText() {
      inputField.setText("");
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }

   @Override
   public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
      super.setEnabled(enabled);
      inputField.setEnabled(enabled);
      doActionButton.setEnabled(enabled);
   }
}
```

Then we can create our own Action that changes what it does depending on its State. It of course has a State field, state, that will be changed each time the JButton is pressed (or enter is pressed in the JTextField):

```
class GetDataAction extends AbstractAction {

   private GetInputPanel inputPanel;
   private Data data;
   private InputState state = InputState.NAME;

   public GetDataAction(GetInputPanel inputPanel, Data data) {
      super("Get Name");
      this.inputPanel = inputPanel;
      this.data = data;
   }

   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      if (state == InputState.NAME) {
         data.setName(inputPanel.getInputText());
         state = InputState.ADDRESS;
      } else if (state == InputState.ADDRESS) {
         data.setAddress(inputPanel.getInputText());
         state = InputState.CITY;
      } else if (state == InputState.CITY) {
         data.setCity(inputPanel.getInputText());
         state = InputState.DONE;
         System.out.println("Data: " + data);
         putValue(NAME, "");
         inputPanel.setPrompt("");

         inputPanel.setEnabled(false);
      } 

      if (state != InputState.DONE) {
         putValue(NAME, "Get " + state.getText());
         inputPanel.setPrompt("Please Enter Your " + state.getText());
      }
      inputPanel.clearInputText();
   }
}
```

A Data class to hold the data that we are changing with the user's input:

```
class Data {
   private String name;
   private String address;
   private String city;

   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

   public String getAddress() {
      return address;
   }

   public void setAddress(String address) {
      this.address = address;
   }

   public String getCity() {
      return city;
   }

   public void setCity(String city) {
      this.city = city;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return "Data [name=" + name + ", address=" + address + ", city=" + city
            + "]";
   }

}
```

And then a GUI class to put it all together and display everything:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

public class GetSuccessiveInputs {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      Data data = new Data();

      GetInputPanel inputPanel = new GetInputPanel();
      inputPanel.setPrompt("Please enter your name:");
      inputPanel.setAction(new GetDataAction(inputPanel, data));

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("GetSuccessiveInputs");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(inputPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```